# MySQL SELECT queries without LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I am doing a course on Relational Databases, MySQL to be more especific. We need to create some SELECT queries for a project. The project is related to music. It has tables to represent musicians (musician), bands (band) and the musician ability to do a certain task, like singing or playing the guitar (act).

Table `musician` contains :

```
id
name
stagename
startyear
```

Table `band` contains :

```
code
name
type ("band" or "solo")
startyear
```

And finally, table `act` contains :

```
band     (foreign key to code of "band" table)
musician (foreign key to id of "musician" table)
hability (guitarist, singer, like that... and a foreign key to another table)
earnings
```

I have doubts in two exercises, the first one asks to select musicians `id` and `stagename` who participate with more acts in bands whose type is `solo`.

My solution for the first one is this:

```
SELECT ma.id, ma.stagename
FROM musician ma, act d, band ba
WHERE ma.id = d.musician
AND ba.code = d.band
AND ba.type = "solo"
GROUP BY ma.id, ma.stagename
HAVING COUNT(ma.id) = (SELECT COUNT(d2.musician) AS count
                        FROM act d2, band ba2
                        WHERE d2.band = ba2.code
                        AND ba2.type = "solo"
                        GROUP BY d2.musician
                        ORDER BY count DESC
                        LIMIT 1);
```

The second one is very similar to the last one. We need to select, for every `startyear`, the `id` and `stagename` of a musician who can do more acts, with the corresponding number of acts and the maximum and minimum of his cachet. This is my solution:

```
SELECT ma.startyear, ma.id, ma.stagename, COUNT(ma.id) AS NumActs, MIN(d.earnings), MAX(d.earnings) 
FROM musician ma, act d, band ba
WHERE ma.id = d.musician
AND ba.code = d.band
AND ba.type = "solo"
GROUP BY ma.year, ma.id, ma.stagename
HAVING COUNT(ma.id) = (SELECT COUNT(d2.musician) AS count
                        FROM act d2, band ba2
                        WHERE d2.band = ba2.code
                        AND ba2.type = "solo"
                        GROUP BY d2.musician
                        ORDER BY count DESC
                        LIMIT 1);
```

The results with my dummy data are perfect but my teacher told us we should avoid using the `LIMIT` option, but that's the only way we can get the highest number, at least with what we know right now.

I've seen a lot of subqueries after the `FROM` statement to solve this problem, however, for this project we can't use subqueries inside `FROM`. Is this really possible without `LIMIT` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some sample data and desired output as formatted text would be helpful

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you need, but you can (and should) use the musician's id in the subquery,  so as a simplified example: `select * from Musician m where 3 < (select count(*) from Act a where a.musician = m.id)` to  get all musicians that are in more than 3 acts. I'm pretty sure you actually need that to get a good result.

Comment: @GolezTrol what i understand is that he wants to get 'not all musician' but one musician with the most act. so there have to be a single line result without providing any count variable to query.

Comment: Your first query, what's the purpose of `GROUP BY` without aggregation.  Probably need to learn `GROUP BY` some more.

Comment: 'Solo' seems redundant. Presumably, if a band has more than one member, it's no longer 'solo'!?!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but much worse than with sub-query in from or limit. So I'd never use it in real life :)

Well, long story short, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
      m.id
    , m.stagename
FROM
    musician m
    INNER JOIN act a ON (
            a.musician = m.id
    )
    INNER JOIN band b ON (
            b.code = a.band
        AND b.type = 'solo'
    )
GROUP BY
      m.id
    , m.stagename
HAVING
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            act a2
            INNER JOIN band b2 ON (
                    b2.code = a2.band
                AND b2.type = 'solo'
            )
        WHERE
            a2.musician != a.musician
        GROUP BY
            a2.musician
        HAVING
            COUNT(a2.musician) > COUNT(a.musician)
    )
;
```

I think you can understand the idea from the query itself as it's pretty straightforward. However, let me know if you need an explanation.

It is possible that your restriction was slightly different and you were not allowing to use subquery in your main FROM part only.

P.S. I'm also use INNER JOIN ... ON syntax as it is easier to see what are table join conditions and what are where conditions.

P.P.S. It might be mistakes in query as I do not have your data structure so cannot execute the query and check. I only checked if the idea works with my test table.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**  I just re-read the question; my initial reading missed that inline views are disallowed.

We can avoid the `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1` construct by making the subquery into an inline view (or, a "derived table" in the MySQL parlance), and using a `MAX()` aggregate.

As a trivial demonstration, this query:

```
 SELECT b.foo
   FROM bar b
  ORDER
     BY b.foo DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

can be emulated with this query:

```
SELECT MAX(c.foo) AS foo
  FROM ( 
         SELECT b.foo
           FROM bar b
       ) c
```

---

An example re-write of the first query in the question

```
SELECT ma.id
     , ma.stagename
  FROM musician ma
  JOIN act d
    ON d.musician = ma.id
  JOIN band ba
    ON ba.code = d.band
 WHERE ba.type = 'solo' 
 GROUP
    BY ma.id
     , ma.stagename
HAVING COUNT(ma.id) 
     = ( SELECT MAX(c.count)
           FROM ( 
                  SELECT COUNT(d2.musician) AS count
                    FROM act d2
                    JOIN band ba2
                      ON ba2.code = d2.band
                   WHERE ba2.type = 'solo'
                   GROUP
                      BY d2.musician
                ) c
       )
```

NOTE: this is a demonstration of a rewrite of the query in the question; this makes no guarantee that this query (or the query in the question) are guaranteed to return a result that satisfies any particular specification. And the specification given in the question is not at all clear.